# Explaining JS closures in the terms of perl

Tags: javascript, perl

I understand without any problems how `perl`'s closures works, like the next one

```
use 5.012;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub countdown {
        my $start = shift;
        return sub { $start-- }
}

my $c10 = countdown(3);
say while( $_ = $c10->() );
```

I'm trying to understand the next piece of Javascript:

```
var runInSandbox = (function(js, inputPath) {

  (function() {
    if ((!context.initialized__QUERY)) {
      return createContext();
    };
  })();
  (function() {
    if (typeof(inputPath) !== 'undefined') {
      (process.argv)[1] = inputPath;;
      (context)["__dirname"] = path.dirname(inputPath);;
      return (module)["filename"] = inputPath;;
    };
  })();
  return vm.runInContext(js, context, "sibilant");
});
```

NO CHANCE! :( ***PLEASE*** *can someone rewrite the above to* ***perl*** ? I know perl a bit - so for me will be extremely useful to understanding JS basics and the constructions like:

```
(...)() - more precisely
(function(){.....})()
```

double `((` in the if

```
    if ((!context.initialized__QUERY)) {
```

or the next

```
      (context)["__dirname"] = something ;;
```

or

```
       return (module)["filename"] = inputPath;; // why double ;;?
```

And if someone coul'd suggest me any resource something like: `Learning Javascript for perl programmers` - would be very nice ;)

Ps: the JS (shortened) is from here: https://github.com/jbr/sibilant/blob/master/lib/cli.js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not extremely well-versed with Perl closures, so I will at least try to demystify this for you.

The form:

```
(function(...) {
 ...
})();
```

is a self-invoked anonymous function<sup>1</sup>. This means that you write out an anonymous function, and then invoke it immediately. This is usually done for encapsulation<sup>2</sup>. For example, if you end up creating a bunch of variables, but don't want it to pollute the global namespace, you can put it inside an anonymous, self-invoked function. However, in this case I don't see why the first invocation is necessary at all, since it's simply checking a flag or something. What is even stranger is the `return` inside those self-invoked functions. They aren't being assigned to anything. I would hazard a guess that `createContext()` initializes the `context` variable, but that `return` in there is effectively useless. The same goes for the following:

```
return (module)["filename"] = inputPath;;
```

As far as the double `((` and `))`, they seem to be largely unnecessary and so I'm not sure why the author originally put it in there. For example:

```
if ((!context.initialized__QUERY))
```

Isn't any different from:

```
if (!context.initialized__QUERY)
```

Also, the parentheses in the following are also unnecessary, as are the double semicolons:

```
(context)["__dirname"] = something ;;
```

Honestly, it just looks like poorly-written Javascript, or perhaps JavaScript that was autogenerated (this is most probably the case).

You could rewrite it like so:

```
var runInSandbox = function(js, inputPath) {

    if (!context.initialized__QUERY) {
       createContext();
    };

    if (typeof inputPath !== 'undefined') {
       process.argv[1] = inputPath;
       context["__dirname"] = path.dirname(inputPath);
       module["filename"] = inputPath;
    };

    return vm.runInContext(js, context, "sibilant");
};
```

---

Notes:

1. In Perl, that would be `sub { ... }->()`.
2. In Perl, one would use `{ my $var; ... }` instead of `sub { my $var; ... }->()` and `do { my $var; ...; EXPR }` instead of `sub { my $var; ...; return EXPR; }->()`.

Comment: Re: "Honestly, it just looks like poorly-written Javascript": Or automatically-generated in some way.

Comment: I don't know JS, but if your rewrite is doing the same as in the OP's question, than your **IS understandable** and clean ;)

Comment: @ruakh just checked - youre right - the above code is GENERATED. Accpeting the answer because helped me with self-invoked functions. Thank you very much. ;)

Comment: I added a couple of tie-ins to Perl in footnotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what it should look like in perl.

```
my $runInSandbox = sub {
     local($js, $inputPath) = ($_[0], $_[1]);
     sub{if (!$context.initialized_QUERY) {
         &createContext();
     }}->();
     sub{ if (defined($inputPath) {
         $process{"argv"][1] = inputPath;
         $context{"__dirname"} = &$path{"dirname"}(inputPath);
         $module["filename"] = inputPath;
     } }->();
     return &$vm{"runInContext"}($js,$context,"sibilant");
};
```

Comment: This won't even compile. `&{...}` is a coderef dereferencing syntax. You may have thought of `do{...}` blocks, which are much like `sub{...}->()`, and quite unneccessary here.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to literally translate the js, but I guess my perl's rustier than I thought. ;)